# Is there a way to override the distance limit on a DJI Mavic Mini without a mobile phone app?

Tags: distance-limit, dji-mavic-mini, smartphone-app

I recently bought a DJI Mavic Mini.

It seems to me, that DJI wants me to fly it with a mobile app, but I currently don't have access to a mobile phone (extremely weak battery only). It looks like I can only fly some 50 meters without the app.

I'd like to override this because I am on a wide field with (almost) no obstacles. I looked into the app, but the distance limits there seem to apply only for the flight with the app.

The instructions given along with the drone are quite minimal and not helpful in this case.

**Is there a way to override the distance limit on a DJI Mavic Mini without using the mobile phone app?**

Comment: Is your drone carrying anything? This distance limit is automatically enabled when the drone is carrying something, but it can also happen if you have the prop guards on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently no, barring exploiting vulnerabilities on the platform (which DJI are pretty quick at fixing) there is no way around the distance limit. The wide field really won't be your issue here. At 60m you can't see it safely line of sight.

Why not get a cheap phone just for this purpose? Doesn't need to be fully featured, or indeed that current - just check compatibility with DJI first.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am able to see it, because I follow it for that purpose, but don't want to land all the time in order to reset the home point (I'm talking about a max distance of 100m) :P But I'll look into getting an other phone.

Answer (score 3):

This distance limit comes up in two circumstances.

Firstly, the drone locks you into this mode when you first get it, and then switches to normal mode after some time. There's no way around it.

Secondly, it automatically enables this mode when it has a payload (the drone is carrying something), although it can sometimes be confused by the prop guards.

You don't need the app constantly to fly. I have the same issue with a weak phone battery, I just connect it to the controller long enough to unlock geo zones and perform calibration, then I disconnect the phone and I can still fly LoS.